# Pure statistical, or Natural Language Processing engine?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, opennlp, statistics

What are the statistical engines that yield better results than the OpenNLP suite of tools, if any? What I'm looking for is an engine that picks keywords from texts and provides stemming on those verbs & nouns, perhaps Natural Language Processing is not the way to go here. The engine should also work with different languages.

Comment: How can NLP not be "the way to go here"? What you describe is exactly an NLP problem.

Comment: I don't see anything statistical about the techniques you're trying to use.

Comment: I'm new to NLP and text mining. As I have heard that some people use NLP for text mining, but these are dependent on models for each language. I have heard that there are pure statistical engines that work on most languages and that I don't need a model for each language. I'm worried that I won't find models for all required languages, I'm Norwegian and OpenNLP don't have models for my language for example.

Comment: @Inge: stemming is usually done by a hand-coded algorithm that knows about the prefixes and postfixes that you're likely to find in the langauge. An example of this in English is the the Porter stemmer, which has nothing statistical in its operation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LingPipe is probably worth a look as complete NLP tool.

However, if all you need to do is find verbs and nouns and stem them, then you could just
1) tokenize text
2) run a POS tagger
3) run a stemmer

The Stanford tools can do this for multiple languages I believe, and NLTK would be a quick way to try it out.

However, you want to be careful of just going after verbs and nouns- what do you do about noun phrases and multiword nouns? Ideally an nlp package can handle this, but a lot of it depends on the domain you are working in. Unfortunately a lot of NLP is how good your data is.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) project, which has developed stemmers for a number of different languages.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for Java code, I can recommend [Stanford's set of tools](http://nlp.stanford.edu/). Their [POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) works for English, German, Chinese and Arabic (though I only used it for English) and includes an (English-only) lemmatizer.

These tools are all free, accuracy is pretty high and the speed is not too bad for a Java-based solution; the main problems are sometimes flaky APIs and high memory use.

Answer (score 1):

I had good experience with TreeTagger:

http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/corplex/TreeTagger/

It's easy to use, faster than the Stanford's one, and belongs to the "good" stemmers/taggers out there. It does all operations at once: tokenization/stemming/tagging.

Comment: Interesting, but it has a commercial license. I was hoping for something free.

Comment: it's not really easy to use, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503388/treetagger-installation-successful-but-cannot-open-par-file

Comment: @2er0: Ok, let me paraphrase it: it's easier to use than many others ;P