# Running TreeTagger

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger

I'm attempting to run TreeTagger using the French parameter file but I am getting a permission denied error with the french-utf8.par file

```
    [bash]:echo cmd/tree-tagger-french-utf8 | lib/french-utf8.par
    [bash]:lib/french-utf8.par: Permission denied
```

This is quite similar to this question here ([TreeTagger installation successful but cannot open .par file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503388/treetagger-installation-successful-but-cannot-open-par-file)), but I'm able to run the tagger like this:

```
    [bash]: echo 'Bonjour' | cmd/tree-tagger-french-utf8
reading parameters ...
tagging ...
 Bonjour    NOM bonjour
 finished.
```

I've tried changing to echo bin/tree-tagger, but I get the same error. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo cmd/tree-tagger-french-utf8` will print the string `cmd/tree-tagger-french-utf8` and you're piping that to a par file. That cannot work, you need to pipe a file to a command, like in your second example but using `cat filename` (instead of `echo 'Bonjour'`) if you want to feed a file to the TreeTagger.

Comment: thank you! i would have never thought of that by reading the README alone. if you are familiar with treetagger, do you know how to save the output in a file. readme suggests this : tree-tagger {-options-} <parameter file> {<input file> {<output file>}}, but i'm not convinced!

Comment: Not treetagger specific, but you can always redirect a command's output by appending " > name_of_output" to the command.

Answer (score 0):

Thats strange, I know this may seem obvious but have you tried running that command as sudo?

The "Permission Denied" hints that there is some permission problem.